# How can I make npm link work with webpack？

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6

I use npm link & dynamic import

when I run npm run dev
product most of error

webpack config

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    symlinks: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  },
```

my index,js

```
import { a } from "moduleA";
a
```

moudle A

```
import(`moduleB`).then(
    (obj) => {
      console.log(obj);
    },
    err => console.log
  );
```

moduleA and moduleB npm link global